# Commerce 2 how to set to live paypal signature API Credentials

Tags: 8, commerce, payment-gateways

I have set up a sandbox account and I can take TEST payments without issue but there is nowhere for the live account details.

If I set the app you can create to live it gives different account API settings but no signature.

It seems Paypal has changed the layout and the PayPal module in D8 commerce 2 and has no help docs as of yet for this just help documents for the old D7 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I sussed this out quicker than I expected. So for anyone else having this issue do this..

1. Login to the merchant account NOT the developer account.
2. Menu on Top right *Click Profile > Profile and settings*
3. *My selling preferences > API access > update*
4. Under *Pre-built payment solution > Manage API permission*
5. Under *Option 2  > View API Signature*
6. Under *View or Remove API Signature* expose the fields to show the Credential API Signature, API Username, API Password.

Add these to your PayPal settings in the commerce payment making sure you set this to live.